# What does the WCF action stand for

Tags: wcf, soap, fault

What does the soap action `http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher/fault` mean?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.
WCF throws a fault code when it an exception is thrown.
Main issue is its not a SOAP xml response and thus many consuming applications do not know how to handle it.